# Add values from list to dictionary in python

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list `li=['project1','project2','project3']`
I want to add these values as key to dictionary and value of first key should be completed rest onhold

projects can be any and value of first project in list should be completed rest onhold
output required:

```
dict={'project1':'completed','project2':'onhold','project3':'onhold'}
```

```
li=['project1','project2','project3']
for trav_cont in li:
   dict[trav_cont]='completed'
```

Comment: You can use `zip()`: `my_dict = dict(zip(li, ('completed',) + ('onhold',) * (len(li) - 1)))`. **Do not use `dict` as name of variable, you're shadowing build-in function.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for idx, key in enumerate(li):
    if idx == 0:
        dixt[key] = 'completed'
        continue
    dict[key] = 'onhold'
```

Comment: Just use `else`, you don't need `continue` there.

Answer (score 5):

You might use `enumerate` to know position in list, i.e.:

```
li=['project1','project2','project3']
dct = {i: 'completed' if inx==0 else 'onhold' for inx, i in enumerate(li)}
print(dct) # {'project1': 'completed', 'project2': 'onhold', 'project3': 'onhold'}
```

I used so-called dict-comprehension here, combined with ternary if, so value is `'completed'` if its first element (has index 0 as python indices are 0-based) else `'onhold'`

Answer (score 3):

You can create a dictionary with predetermined keys and a default `value`:

```
my_dict = dict.fromkeys(li, 'onhold')
my_dict['project1'] = 'completed'
```

Gives:

```
{'project1': 'completed', 'project2': 'onhold', 'project3': 'onhold'}
```

Comment: This is the cleanest answer.

Comment: But the name will not always be project1 it should be dynamic

Comment: @shee8, you can use `my_dict[next(iter(my_dict))] = 'completed'` to set value for first key. *(It will work only on python 3.6+)*